# Control Windows Command Prompt from Python

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to programmatically shut down mysqld from python on a windows 7 machine.

I have tried the following commands in windows command prompt manually:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqladmin" -u demo shutdown -p demopw
```

I then receive the following prompt:

```
Enter Password:
```

After I manually type in the password, mysqld shuts down.

My problem is, I need to do this automatically within python.  I have read one or two other posts that I could find, and have searched for quite a while for an answer that works.  Thus far, I have tried many variations with popen, and subprocess.Popen, to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-p` argument to `mysql` and `mysqladmin` et al is funky in that you absolutely can *not* have a space between the `-p` and the password.

So try

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqladmin" -u demo -pdemopw shutdown
```

Comment: Wow.  Thanks so much.  Just want to note that there is no semicolon after shutdown for anyone who sees this in the future.

Comment: I have tried to use the above command using os.system(...), and it does not actually stop the server.  Any ideas why?